# Using special tags for php in html

Tags: php, html

I've done a bit of research before asking this question, although i've had 0 luck.

What i'm trying to figure out is pretty much how I can make kinda of a template system. I know I could look at how others are done, but I just thought i'd ask to get a simple answer.

Pretty much I want to be able to use something like `{Name} or %name%` in html, which obviously comes from valuables in a PHP file.

So for example, In a PHP file I have, I have the valuable of `$Name == "My Name";`
Instead of putting PHP into the html which would look messy which would be `<?php echo $Name; ?>` I'd like to be able to use `%Name% or {Name}` instead.

Hopefully someone can understand what I mean, and help me out.

Thank you

Comment: Why you want create own template system?

Comment: Why not use an existing templating system like blade or twig for example.

Comment: Its not exactly going to be a template system, But I want to be able to integrate it into a system I have already got, which would possibly mean more work on using an existing one, then using some code and integrating it. Sorry, I'm pretty bad at explaining things. But I pretty much want it how I want it. I don't want to use an existing template system. I just want to be able to use {name} which links to $name.

Comment: use a `preg_replace` for your "temaplate-system"

Comment: If you just whish to replace simple markers then you could use `str_replace()` or `preg_replace()` to do so.

Comment: Take a look at [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) it is a pretty versatile template engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, you are looking for [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), this will do the job of replacing the `keyword` with a actual value. I sometimes use it like so:

```
$template = file_get_contents('test.php');
$name = 'Mrs. Happy Dash.';

//Preps keywords in the template that needs to be replaced with our data.
$keywords = array
(
    "{TITLE}" => 'Thank you for visiting',
    "{INTRO}" => 'I hope you enjoyed your stay ' . $name,
    "{SUB_INTRO}" => '<p style="color:red;">REMEMBER TO PAY!</p>',
    "{ORDER_SUMMARY}" => '1x Sky diving class - 10 Euro',
    "{HOWTOPAY_TITLE}" => 'You can pay like this:',
    "{HOWTOPAY}" => 'Credit card',
    "{FOOTER}" => 'Bye bye'
);

//Replaces the data in the template
foreach($keywords as $search => $data){
    $template = str_replace($search, $data, $template);
}

echo $template;
```

You can practically use anything you want as keywords, `%NAME%`,`#NAME#`. As long as you write them in the keywords array.

The data you are using to replace the `keywords` can also contain HTML, which is useful if you want to show different styles depending on certain options / criteria.

The above example is of course very rough and can be improved in many ways but it should offer a simple and easy way to do it (and it's easy to adjust to a more personal need / taste).

Comment: Hi @Gesset remember to accept either of the answers if they solved your issue / worked for you.

Comment: Hi, I've decided to use this technique. Although how would I be able to load pages and be able to use {TITLE} on it. At the moment I've tried including. Such as $template = include "test.php"; Although this doesnt allow those tags to be used. How would you suggest I'd get around this?

Comment: Is test.php purely html? Also instead of include you might want to use `file_get_contents();` I'll update my answer.

Comment: Hi, How would I be able to use php code inside this. So for example I want to use the {TITLE} tags, but I can't use them everywhere, so how could I use the value of something like $Title = "Site Name" and for it to show $Title.

Comment: @Gesset Not sure I understand

Comment: Okay, so. With this I can use {TITLE} which will give me whatever I want. But by using file_get_contents to grab it all, it stops me from executing php inside the file im grabbing. So if I have all your code in a file called config.php and inside that config.php I also have $TITLE = "Hey"; and in the main page which im grabbing it all from using file_get_contents i'm using both {TITLE} which works, and trying to use $Title, $Title doesnt work. How can I get around this? Sorry that i'm terrible at explaining things. I appreciate your help

Comment: @Gesset http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/vmiz-yg6h Should give you an' idea, it's important that the EOT in your HTML file isn't indented or have any spaces and is on it's own line.

Answer (score 1):

just do a string replace:

```
public function _output($tpl, $values) {
    if(!is_readable($tpl)) {
        return ['err'=>'The ('.$tpl.') template is missing or unreadable!'];
    }

    $output = file_get_contents($tpl);
    if($output === false){
        return ['err'=>'Error loading template file ('.$tpl.')'];
    }

    foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
        $tagToReplace = "[@".$key."]";
        $output = str_replace($tagToReplace, $value, $output);
    }

    return $output;
}
```

usage:

`_output('path/to/html/file', ['key'=>'value', 'key'=>'value'])`

Here is the breakdown:

1. Make sure that the html template file exists and is readable
2. Read the template file into a string
3. Replace known placeholders with real values

Your html file might look like this:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>[@site_title]</title>

    <script src="[@polymer_elements]webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="[@polymer_elements]paper-styles/paper-styles.html">
    <link rel="import" href="[@polymer_elements]paper-styles/paper-styles-classes.html">
    <link rel="import" href="[@polymer_elements]paper-header-panel/paper-header-panel.html">
    <link rel="import" href="[@polymer_elements]paper-drawer-panel/paper-drawer-panel.html">
    <link rel="import" href="[@polymer_elements]paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html">
    <link rel="import" href="[@polymer_elements]iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout.html">
    <link rel="import" href="[@polymer_elements]iron-media-query/iron-media-query.html">
    <link rel="import" href="[@custom_elements]universal/ajax-widgets-loader/ajax-widgets-loader.html">
    <link rel="import" href="[@custom_elements]universal/ajax-app-loader/ajax-app-loader.html">
  </head>
```

So assuming you have an array like `array('polymer_elements'=>'path/to/polymer/folder/', 'site_title'=>'my site title')`

Your final output from php will be like

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>my site title</title>

    <script src="path/to/polymer/folder/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="path/to/polymer/folder/paper-styles/paper-styles.html">
    <link rel="import" href="path/to/polymer/folder/paper-styles/paper-styles-classes.html">
    <link rel="import" href="path/to/polymer/folder/paper-header-panel/paper-header-panel.html">
    <link rel="import" href="path/to/polymer/folder/paper-drawer-panel/paper-drawer-panel.html">
    <link rel="import" href="path/to/polymer/folder/paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html">
    <link rel="import" href="path/to/polymer/folder/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout.html">
    <link rel="import" href="path/to/polymer/folder/iron-media-query/iron-media-query.html">
    <link rel="import" href="path/to/polymer/folder/universal/ajax-widgets-loader/ajax-widgets-loader.html">
    <link rel="import" href="path/to/polymer/folder/universal/ajax-app-loader/ajax-app-loader.html">
  </head>
```

NB: To all the people saying "use smarty", I think smarty and all the other template engines are good. They are developed by a larger community and not just one person, but sometimes we just need a little snippet and not a whole library.